# Is there any vscode plugin to sync between folders in different machine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization, vscode-remote

In my organization , the development machines are in office network and lab environment is in private network. Due to this code will be written in lab environment then we will copy it to office network and push the changes.

Doing this manually is error prone. Is there any plugin available in VS code to compare a folder in local machine and remote machine then sync?

I would like to sync between folders in different machine

```
/root/labfolder/feb4  <-> root@devmachine:/root/devFolder/feb4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sftp extension. You can also upload a file on save. See this documentation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp